# Example of Android MVVM + Databinding + Architecture Components (ViewModel and Room)

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

Could someone provide me a not complicated example of working project on GitHub, which is using:
- MVVM
- Databinding
- Architecture Components - ViewModel and Room

All examples and articles on Medium which I have found already have not using all of this and for me on my level of experience is hard to combine it in one project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn MVVM & Recommended architecture by Android. This repo shows that how to use LiveData, Room Persistence, Dagger 2, Retrofit, MVVM and DataBinding.

Look at this and download from this link :
[AndroidArchitecture](https://github.com/JaydipRadadiya/AndroidArchitecture)

Hope you can do that!